# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS doesn't detect Lumia 540

Tags: kernel, hardware-enablement-stack

The same detects in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and file transfer becomes easy. I have tried Ubuntu LTS enablement kernel. It ended up in DM crash. However, my question is, how to add it module wise?

Comment: A more interesting question is why do you think you need 14.04?

Comment: because I'm having low-end-machine

Comment: How worse 16.04 or 17.04 perform compared to 14.04? Yeah, they don't. New hardware, newer release.

Comment: Consumption of RAM differs from each other. Never mind.